Applying to two PhD positions under the same professor at the same time?
There are other related questions but they are the cases where professors are different as opposed to mine so asking here. In my scenario both the PhD projects are basically two inter-related modules of the same big research project being advertised by the same professor. The job requirements and expertise required are exactly the same so are the benefits and everything. So is it generally okay to apply to maximize my chances or does this create  a bad impression?
P.S: I am applying for a PhD at the Aerospace department of TU Delft, Netherlands.

Were there two separate announcements for the positions, or one, listing both?

@Buffy two separate announcements.

Voting to leave open. Those voting to close should note that this question and its answers will be applicable to others, not just the OP. Also, that the "individual factors" close text includes "Note that questions on the rules of institutions that operate at national or international level are permitted."

Different institutions (and different professors) will want to handle this in different ways. I think the best thing you can do is query the professor, be honest that you are keen on both projects, and ask how they would like you to proceed.

Agreed. And there's nothing wrong or awkward with this - a professor will be happy that the candidate is interested in multiple research directions, and they can direct the candidate towards the project that either suits the candidate better, benefits the professor/institute more, or ideally both.

It may also be that there is not a strong mapping from project to positions - eg project has goals A, B, C but enough funding for 2 students. Prof decides to advertise for a position for A and a position for B, but what they're really interested in is getting two people who are interested in all A/B/C. You'd only find this out by asking.

Another advantage of this is that the professor might say something like "with your background you should apply for position A and not position B", and then you saved yourself and the committee a bunch of work.

Assuming that the two people that get accepted have to work somewhat close together, it's also possible that they plan to have "group interviews" to see how the applicants get along with each other. In that case, they might prefer to have one application expressing interest in both positions instead of two almost identical applications.

It seems perfectly reasonable to me for an applicant to apply for both positions concurrently.  Given that both advertisements use the same selection criteria the applications to both will be similar.  It is worth noting in each application that you have applied for both positions and would be happy to accept either role.  As far as the impression this makes, I would take it as a positive if an applicant is interested in both aspects of the research project --- it would be more strange if they apply for one position but not the other.

I can image a lot of cases, were one PhD positions is interesting and the one with a different angle would not be of interest. For example in an inter-disciplinary project I would work as a mathematician, computer scientist, or data engineer - not as a chemist or social scientist.

@usr1234567: Whilst that is common, those cases would have very different selection criteria for positions.  The fact that the job requirements are the same for both positions (in the present case) probably precludes those types of cases.

It is worth querying upfront how to apply for both positions - it could be there's an entirely separate application process (different committee etc) for each, or it could be the applications process is joint (same people read both applications, one set of interviews for both positions on the same day, etc). They may say you need to apply twice or you can apply once and express interest in both positions, it depends a lot on how their hiring process works.

Given that there were two separate announcements, I'd suggest you make two applications, but each referencing the other. But they shouldn't be identical.
Distinguish each by your special qualifications for that specific project module and make it clear at the beginning which module it refers to.
You can end with a statement to the effect that you would be happy to take either role and have interest in both.
Other scenarios would lead me to make different suggestions, however.

As someone who has been in a similar situation and based on my experience, I would advise against doing this as you risk coming across as indecisive and you may be asked difficult questions during your interview. Instead, if you still have time before the application deadline, I would recommend to try to arrange a meeting with the intended promotor(s) to discuss both positions, to find out which is the better fit, and then apply for this one. With this, you show that you are genuinely interested in their group and not just applying to all positions you can find. You will also become more familiar to the professors when you send in your application, which could improve your chances of getting hired.

I think this would definitely be a concern if the projects were different. I don't think it's a worry because the projects are closely related. I agree with contacting the professor - maybe they would prefer a single application to one of them (and can guide which), maybe they would like a single app that says it's for either, and maybe they would prefer two applications. Either way, yoru last sentence is definitely true!

Imagine that the two best qualified applicants all apply to position A. Then only one of them gets it. Position B will be filled with someone much less qualified than the student who did not get position A. This is way less optimal than the case of both students applying to both positions, both being picked, and then assigned to one position each.
